# How to configure Audience targetting for Group calendar?

Tags: web-part, audience-targeting, hide-elements

My SharePoint Team site contains a Group Calendar web part. In addition to members of the standard MS365 group, there are also members of another group who have access to this site. Users of the Team site who are not members of this Team group will receive a message that the Group no longer exists. Is there a way to use Audience targeting for the web part Group calendar to prevent this or is there another option?